# What is wrong with this substring-matching algorithm?

Tags: c#

At a recent interview I was asked to write an algorithm which:

*Given a string `text`, and string `subtext`, finds the starting character positions of each subtext found within the text.*

```
"hey hi how are you hi" = 5, 20
```

I was forbidden to use any `System.String` functions (`Substring`, `IndexOf` etc).

I wrote this in C#:

```
IEnumerable<int> CalculateSubtextPositions(string text, string subtext)
{
    var charIndexToMatch = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] != subtext[charIndexToMatch])
            charIndexToMatch = 0;

        if (text[i] == subtext[charIndexToMatch])
        {
            charIndexToMatch++;
            if (charIndexToMatch == subtext.Length)
            {
                yield return i - charIndexToMatch + 2;
                charIndexToMatch = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which was described as 'disappointing'. It may well be I've missed something, but I can't see what's hugely wrong with the above. It works, it's efficient, and reasonably easy to read compared to many approaches (at least in my opinion, please correct me if I'm wrong).

Would people be able to suggest where I might have messed up? It may have been because I was asked to make the code 'reusable', but I'm not sure to what extent that can be applied when you're only asked to write an algorithm.

Please do criticise! :)

Comment: Did they offer any feedback beyond describing it as "disappointing"? I haven't checked whether it would definitely work, but it looks like a very neat solution to the challenge to me. I'd put it down to the interviewer being a "expert beginner" or similar poor quality developer who probably didn't understand `yield` and didn't want to admit it to you. You are likely better off not working there, therefore...

Comment: Are you sure it works? Suppose the input text is "aaabc" and the text to find is "aabc". Also consider "aaaa" and "aa". Did you ask the interviewer about overlapping matches? Similar problems arise constantly in real-world programming. Serious companies are looking for the people who will find and resolve those problems before the code is delivered.

Comment: Also "charIndexToMatch" is unnecessarily long but worse, doesn't say which of the two strings it is indexing. "subtextIndex" would be shorter and better. All this is off-topic here. Maybe repost to Code Review.

Comment: @DavidArno: The interviewer should have asked the candidate about the failing test cases, rather than just saying it was "disappointing". However, this code would not meet the bar at most of the places I have worked. The use of "yield" is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I don't agree a failed test case scenario would cause you to not meet the bar though (the interview wasn't failed). I'd also find 'subtextIndex' to be confusingly named.

Comment: @user666254: I would probably have called them 't' and 's' and left the rest as an exercise for the reader. Small scope -> short name.

Comment: @kevincline, and those serious companies would not expect someone to work out an algorithm like this on paper .. they'd set up pair-programming sessions and allow the candidate to develop the solution through exploring ideas and TDD. This code would certainly pass such a paper-based test with me as the use of excellent names like `charIndexToMatch` would count far more than working out edge cases in one's head. Each to their own, I guess...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code isn't correct enough.

When you detect a match failure, resetting your match counter to 0 is too aggressive; as kevin pointed out, this can miss valid matches if the **text** is constructed misleadingly. You have to reset to *the last possible global match start position*, and that isn't easy to do. In an interview, I'd probably go for the obvious double-loop solution instead.

Comment: Could you please provide an example which would fail?

Comment: Actually I see your point - well spotted.

Comment: @user666254: I provided two examples in my comments.